# Why does performance drop when a function is moved to another module?

Tags: performance, haskell, typeclass

I am observing that the same fn gives different performance, depending on whether it's placed in the same module where it's used or in a module next to it. Any ideas what could be causing it?

Here's the function:
https://github.com/oshyshko/polymodperf/blob/master/src/Main.hs#L41-L55

```
test :: MArray a t m => (t -> t) -> a Int t -> m ()
test f a =
    mapM_ (\ xy -> do
              v <- get a xy
              set a xy (f v))

          [ (x,y) | y <- [0..1000 - 1],
                    x <- [0..1000 - 1],
                    n <- [0..10]]
  where
    get :: MArray a e m => a Int e -> (Int, Int) -> m e
    get a (x,y) = readArray a (x + y * 1000)

    set :: MArray a e m => a Int e -> (Int, Int) -> e -> m ()
    set a (x,y) = writeArray a (x + y * 1000)
```

In my test pass I use `Data.Array.IO.newArray` to create an array, then pass it to `test`.

Here's how to observe the difference in performance (second value, ms):

```
$ ./scripts/build-exec.sh
...
Main.test
(11000000,2010)
(11000000,239)
(11000000,240)
(11000000,242)
(11000000,237)

SomeModule.test
(11000000,6376)
(11000000,4851)
(11000000,5455)
(11000000,5096)
(11000000,5206)
```

- `Main.test`: both `newArray` and `test` both live in `Main` => okay performance (the first 2010ms run is probably bad due to warmup, but the rest look good)
- `SomeModule.test`: `newArray` lives in `Main`, but `test` is imported from `SomeModule.test` => much worse performance

The code of `test` is identical in both modules:
https://github.com/oshyshko/polymodperf/blob/master/src/Main.hs#L41-L55
https://github.com/oshyshko/polymodperf/blob/master/src/SomeModule.hs#L9-L17

The used `MArray` typeclass and fns `readArray`, `writeArray` imported from the same module in both cases:

```
import           Data.Array.MArray (MArray, readArray, writeArray)
```

Any ideas what could be causing the difference in performance?

Comment: First guess would be inlining. There's the `{-# INLINE test #-}` pragma you can try, but first – do you actually compile with optimisations?

Answer (score 5):

As `leftaroundabout` suggested in a comment, adding `INLINE` pragma solved the problem:

```
test :: MArray a t m => (t -> t) -> a Int t -> m ()
{-# INLINE test #-}
test f a =
    ...
```

https://github.com/oshyshko/polymodperf/blob/master/src/SomeModule.hs#L10